# Vagrant doesn't runs Inline shell script to Install packages

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

All of my packages are not Installed, seems Vagrant doesn't provision Inline shell script by default.

Last time I Installed packages manually but then I ran Into permission Issues, again I tried reinstalling vagrant box but still It doesn't run the Inline script.

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
config.vm.box_version = "= 2.3.5"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000, host_ip:   "127.0.0.1"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

# Work around disconnected virtual network cable.
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]
end

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
apt-get -qqy update

# Work around https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/661
# apt-get -qqy upgrade
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force- confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade

apt-get -qqy install make zip unzip postgresql

apt-get -qqy install python3 python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install flask packaging oauth2client redis passlib flask-httpauth
pip3 install sqlalchemy flask-sqlalchemy psycopg2-binary bleach  requests

apt-get -qqy install python python-pip
pip2 install --upgrade pip
pip2 install flask packaging oauth2client redis passlib flask-httpauth
pip2 install sqlalchemy flask-sqlalchemy psycopg2-binary bleach requests

su postgres -c 'createuser -dRS vagrant'
su vagrant -c 'createdb'
su vagrant -c 'createdb news'
su vagrant -c 'createdb forum'
su vagrant -c 'psql forum -f /vagrant/forum/forum.sql'

vagrantTip="[35m[1mThe shared directory is located at /vagrant\\nTo access your shared files: cd /vagrant[m"
echo -e $vagrantTip > /etc/motd

wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make install

echo "Done installing your virtual machine!"
SHELL
end
```

Comment: you may add vagrant provision output to your question

Answer (score 0):

you can always run one by one the lines of your script to check which one produces an error.

Here I see you have a space on `--force- confdef` you can easily fix with

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
```